# Is there any way to backup our Ask Ubuntu profile?

Tags: support

I have asked 40 questions on Ask Ubuntu. Also I mark more than 20 questions as favorite  question this like a notebook for me. But sometimes I do not have access to the Internet and I wish if there is some thing to backup my profile on my desktop.

Comment: There is no built in way to do this, but it would make an interesting question on the main site.

Comment: @Seth sorry. which stack do you mean for main site? I have another question to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be for you to download the Ask Ubuntu data dump and serve it back to yourself offline:

- https://stackapps.com/questions/3610/stackdump-an-offline-browser-for-stackexchange-sites